# Right usage of topological sort in algorithms

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, graph, topological-sort

Given a sorted dictionary of an alien language having N words and k starting alphabets of standard dictionary the task is to complete the function which returns a string denoting the order of characters in the language.

```
Input:  Dict[] = { "baa", "abcd", "abca", "cab", "cad" }, k = 4
Output: Function returns "bdac" 
Here order of characters is 'b', 'd', 'a', 'c'
```

I already implemented a solution for the question using **topological sort** by referring to some articles online but none of them mentioned how did they arrive at the decision of using topological sort?

**Question:** How can someone possibly know when to use graphs or its concepts like topological sort to solve questions?

**For reference:**

The solution is to traverse the list given and compare each string with the next one. Whenever first mismatch is found, add edge between the two characters in the graph and move on to compare the next two strings.

Once graph is ready, apply topological sort.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to practice more questions and develop an intuition to solve the problems. As for topological you can start with identifying some flags where you might be able to use topological sort . 
**1.** Is the flag a **Directed Acyclic Graph**(DAG)since topological sort can only be applied to DAG 
**2.** Can the graph be converted to a **DAG** by some manipulation, like your example. A directed graph can be converted into a DAG by merging its **Strongly Connected Components** or can you reduce the problem somehow into a DAG 
**3.** Do you need some kind of linear among the nodes ? 
**4.** Do you want to find the shortest path(The topological ordering can also be used to quickly compute shortest paths through a weighted directed acyclic graph)

That's all I have for now, I'll keep updating this answer later

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the way I would think about graph is that it represents relationships between objects. Here, the objects are alphabets, and you are trying to figure out one of the three cases (for two letters x and y):

1) letter x comes before y

2) letter y comes before x

3) x and y can come in any order

However, since 1 and 2 cannot happen simultaneously, we have a DAG (directed acyclic graph). So, "trying to find an order in a DAG" **rings the bell** for topological sort. In fact, the problem is now very similar to the classical problem used for teaching topological sort, i.e., we have a bunch tasks and task x should be done before task y, and so on, find a valid order for tasks to be done.

However, as in every other skill in life being able to distinguish what algorithm to use immediately, is a result of experience and lots of practice :)